# "acquaint" vs. "introduce"

Tags: word-usage

A [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/214570/109190) says

> If you are **acquainted** with the other person to whom you are referring

which uses the verb "acquainted with" with people.

the definition about "acquaint" on Cambridge Dictionary is with something.

> to make someone or yourself familiar with something.

I didn't consider that use before, now I do.

Imagine that, Michael and Albert are friends of Schmidhuber and they don't know each other.

Michael wants to know Albert, but he thinks it would be impolite to contact Albert directly. So, Michael asks Schmidhuber does him a favor.

With Schmidhuber's help, Michael get acquainted with Albert.

I guess it is idiomatic to say

> Schmidhuber **introduced** Michael to Albert.

where "introduce" means "help to know".

## question

Is it idiomatic to say the following?

> Schmidhuber **acquainted** Michael with Albert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British English, **acquaint** is very formal. As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acquaint%20himself%2Cacquaint%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacquaint%20himself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacquaint%20him%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cacquaint%20himself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacquaint%20him%3B%2Cc0) shows, its usage peaked about 1820 and fell rapidly till 1900: since then its usage has continued to decline.

Looking at actual instances of its use both in the 1820's and in modern times, it is typically used more for acquiring information that for getting to know a person.

> Schmidhuber acquainted Michael with Albert.

This sentence is grammatically correct and understandable, however it is not at all natural in current usage. The **introduce** version is more current.

I would generally only use **acquaint** in a formal, written document, and only when it concerns familiarisation with ideas. For example:

> We **acquainted ourselves** with Fechner's scientific realism by looking at atomism. - *["Nature from Within: Gustav Theodor Fechner and His Psychophysical Worldview"](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=t8PW5CSFADAC&pg=PA149&dq=%22acquainted%20ourselves%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQkNiBrq3oAhXu4zgGHUhQBf4Q6AEIYjAG#v=onepage&q=%22acquainted%20ourselves%20with%22&f=false), Michael Heidelberger*

One exception which refers to people is the stock phrase "to get acquainted". for example:

> At this point, it would be appropriate to introduce the new employee to the chosen mentor and allow time for the two **to get acquainted** - *[New Employee Orientation Training](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=DDbZS3hNcL0C&pg=PA84&dq=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ0ZyAr63oAhXHdCsKHd3PD54Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&f=false), Karen Lawson*
>
> Alternatively, the event may be seen as positive if the other party is a woman the man finds attractive and he views the incident as an opportunity for the two to get acquainted - *[Encyclopedia of Behavior Modification and Cognitive Behavior](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=4b11AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT417&dq=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ0ZyAr63oAhXHdCsKHd3PD54Q6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&f=false), Michael Hersen*

Having introduced two people, you can use this stock phrase in speech, and it does not sound too pompous:

> Mackall stepped forward, shook Norton's hand and headed for the door. “I will leave you two to get acquainted.” - *[For Love or Honor Bound](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=fXlLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&dq=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ0ZyAr63oAhXHdCsKHd3PD54Q6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=%22two%20to%20get%20acquainted%22&f=false), Derek Hart*

It is easier to say "get acquainted" than say "get to know one another" (four syllables rather than seven), and the latter is a bit too informal for some people. This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20acquainted%2C%20get%20to%20know%20one%20another&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20acquainted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20to%20know%20one%20another%3B%2Cc0) shows that, despite its clumsiness, the informal "get to know one another" is gaining ground.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Would you please make up a situation where "acquaint" is suitable? For instance, Michael gets Albert's phone number and calls him, does this count?

Comment: @WXJ96163 I have added more explanation to my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your work. Would you please explain a bit more why "I will leave you two to get acquainted" is easier to say than "to get to know one another"?

Comment: @WXJ96163 i have updated my answer.

Comment: @Javalatte - it is routine in British English to say that you are acquainted with someone, especially if you wish to imply that the connection is not close or intimate (i.e. you just know them, but you are not friends or close colleagues). It is not super formal. The word is probably less used in lower registers, street slang, youth talk, etc, but it is not severely restricted or obsolete as you seem to imply.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you are right, the passive-voice "aquainted", and also the noun form "acquaintance", have always been more widely used than the active voice "acquaint", though both are also in decline. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acquaint%2Cacquainted%2C+acquaintance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacquaint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacquainted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacquaintance%3B%2Cc0